# laravel get jobs from redis queue located in another codebase\project?

Tags: php, laravel, redis, queue, laravel-5.3

i'm looking for someway to get jobs from laravel queue using redis driver in another codebase.
I have an application server that push transactions (jobs) into the queue using redis-server located on the same machine. I need to connect to this machine  from another machine (lets say internal server\api over the same architecture of the organization) and connect to the redis queue I mentioned before and get the transactions\jobs that stored over there.

My problem is when i'm trying to get the jobs i'm failing to do this because different namespaces between the 2 projects.

I already tried to manipulate the code and having the same job class in both of the servers and also having the same namespace.

Any ideas? or maybe recommendations for another approach?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Did you figure this out where you wouldn't have to duplicate the class and namespace? I'm in this exact situation

Comment: well, i'm not sure its the best practice but its wroking,
i'm using plain sqs, im pushing to queue whatever i want in json format from one codebase\project and im listening to this queue from another codebase.
take a look at - https://github.com/dusterio/laravel-plain-sqs